# Mixing up mythology

Tags: mythology

So I am writing a book in which I want to include gods from different mythologies, like Erebus from greek and Heka from egyptian mythology. but I don't know how I should approach it. Can I like include them as they are, and make it like an open mixed mythology, or like should I make up my own mythology and base the characters on those selected few.

Because I feel that a mixed mythology will be kinda weird.

Comment: It's your story. You don't need anyone's approval except your own.

Answer (score 2):

**Mixing up mythologies is certainly a peculiar idea.**

**Pros:**

- People already know the backstory and hierarchy in the characters.
- Character profiling is easy.

**Cons:**

- The pros will become cons.
- Since there are so many existing ideas on the myths, any minor change will wreak havoc in the Reader's community.
- There is not much space for development of your ideas since the boundaries are already set in the mythical beliefs.
- Every myth has several backstories and it is necessary to be precarious in which path to choose.
- Readers might find a lot of similarities and overlaps in the story with other existing books. It will be like walking on eggshells.

> **Personally, I believe creating a new universe of Gods, rules, and beliefs will be more satisfactory than mixing.**

**Pros:**

- Wider range of characters can be created as your wish.
- Joy of creating an Entire Universe that only you are aware of.
- New rules, different places, new beliefs, sayings, prophecies, attires, language, and etc.
- Loads of area for experimentation.

**Cons:**

- Takes time in ensuring ideas aren't repetitive or offending anyone.
- More concentrated details must be placed in setting the scene.

Whichever you choose, all the best!

Answer (score -1):

Why run before you can walk?

First write three or four stories each touching on any one mythology.

That done, won't the Question have Answered itself?